# Probability of sample means being equal

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, mean, sample

Let $X\sim N(70,16)$ and $Y\sim N(70,9)$. Given a sample of size $n=4$ from $X$ and a sample of size $m=9$ from $Y$, compute

$$
P(\bar X = \bar Y).
$$

Comment: What have you tried so far? This looks eerily like a homework question copy and pasted here.

Comment: Because the sample means have continuous distributions, the chance they are equal must be zero.  Thus, questions of this sort are fruitless: it is meaningful only to ask for the chance that the difference of means might lie within some interval of nonzero length.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Yeah well i said that x̄ - ȳ = d and d~N. Later on another question asks to find the probability of x̄ - ȳ>2 in which case I did this:
P(d>2). Since d is a linear combination of random independent normal variables i said E(d)=E(x̄)-E(ȳ)=0 and V(d)  =  V(x̄)+(-1)^2*V(ȳ)  =  V(x̄)+V(ȳ)=. And after that i get P(Z>0.899427) = 0.81594.
What got me trippin was the equality but its probably as whuber said

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Yes turns out the answear is 0 because X~N and Y~N

Answer (score 4):

By some properties of the normal distribution  (make sure you understand which)

$$\bar X \sim N(70, 16/4), \quad \bar Y \sim N(70, 9/9)$$

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $\bar X - \bar Y = W \sim N(0, 5)$. Therefore

$$
P(\bar X - \bar Y) = P(W = 0)=\cdots
$$

I leave the rest to you...